# Eclipse shows warning for checkstyle SuppresWarnings that exists

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle, suppress-warnings

In my Eclipse (Kepler 4.3) I have Checkstyle installed and working with a proper file (verification also happens through Jenkins). Nonetheless my Eclipse editor gives me a Warning for all my `@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:parameternumber")`

The `parameternumber` value exists in the Checkstyle, as some of the developers do not have this issue. However we compared environments and could not figure our what was different.
Does anyone here have an idea how to fix this issue?

```
public class MyClass {

@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:parameternumber")
public MyClass(...multiple paramters...){
/*Implementation*/
}
```

When I remove this `@SuppresWarnings` I am getting a Checkstyle warning from Eclipse that I am using to many parameters. So it does recognize it I assume.

Comment: Show real code not `...multiple Parameters..`

Comment: they do not matter in this case. But if you prefer I can add; public MyClass(String first, String second, String third, String fourth) and only 3 allowed

Comment: What is the exact warning message?

Comment: Exact warning is: Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:parameternumber") --> http://imgur.com/a/ukUsu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disable Eclipse checking the names in `@SuppressWarnings`, you can do it just like for [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/integrations.html) (exact same steps required):

> To get Eclipse to not flag the @SuppressWarnings("PMD") annotation, look under the menu headings Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Annotations -> Unhandled Warning Token.

Comment: If you find any answer usefull, you can (besides marking as accepted) upvote it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow